# How to Add Radio Buttons to a Form Vertically?

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, radio-button, code-behind

I am dynamically creating radio button within code behind in ASP.Net, how do I add the controls so they appear vertically instead of horizontally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RadioButtonList rbl = new RadioButtonList();
rbl.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Vertical;
```

Comment: var rbl = new RadioButtonList() { RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Vertical }; :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use RadioButtonList Control with RepeatDirection set to Vertical.
If that is not possible then....

Add them to a ordered list(OL element) or an unordered list(UL).

Answer (score 0):

Possible two ways:

- Give some CSS class, and in your css give that class some style like

  `display:block;`
- Use RadioButtonList control as container to those radio buttons. Set the "RepeatDirection" property to "Vertical".